# ant mail task : Limitation on addresses with dot on either sides

Tags: email, ant

My ant script based on the mail task works fine with mail addresses of the form A@B.C where A,B, and C are strings NOT containing dots, '.' .

Alas, I need it to work with addresses of the form:

A.D@B.C and A@E.B.C

which are in common use today.

```
    <mail mailhost="x.com"   mailport="587"   tolist="mail@y.z.com" subject="? was updated.">
         <from address="mail@cvkimball.com"/>
    </mail>
```

Is this a limitation of the ant mail task?

Answer (score 0):

I failed to provide the SMTP server's user and password attributes.

Since I was testing with an e-mail dress on the same server, the server (apparently) didn't check the user and password and my test succeded.